# Firebase phone authentication is not working after upload app on playstore

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, sha1

I have no idea why it is happening. My app works fine with debug apk and signed apk. I have added the SHA1 key to firebase console also. But when i uploaded my app and installed it from Play Store then it is not sending the OTP to my phone number. Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Before uploading have tried in release apk is that was working?

Comment: Yeah, it worked before upload. Now my app is working live also after i added the Google Play Signing Key(SHA1) to the firebase console.

Comment: @Abani where do we have to add google play key (SHA1) in firebase ? 
it is where last sha1 is added ? or somewhere else?

Comment: @ZainabJamil  Go to your project on Firebase console and click on the **Settings** button on top along with the **Project Overview** . Then scroll to bottom and there you can find **Add Fingerprint** option. Add your SHA1 key there. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Did you just enrolled for [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)? In that case your key has changed. You can get SHA1 of the key used to sign your apk from Play Store Console.

Comment: Nope, I didn't enroll for this. Do i have to enroll?

Comment: no, that's optional. it could be the reason had you opted for it.

Comment: Is there any permission related issue? I didn't give any permission for phone authentication in my manifest file

Comment: I don't think so. If it worked with debug and your signed apk then it's something else. Can you reconfirm from Play Store Console that you have not enabled Google Play App Signing?

Comment: Thanks a lot man, i have added the SHA1 key from Play console in Firebase console . Now it's working

Comment: @sandeepd & Abani, I faced the same issue, your solution helped me to fix it. Thanks for saving my day. :) Cheers !!

Comment: It worked, We can find it here in play console:
Release>Setup>App Integrity>

Answer (score 23):

Using these steps you have successfully resolved all issues -:

1. Go to google play console
2. Setup -> App Integrity
3. copy **SHA-1 certificate fingerprint** in (App signing certificate)
4. Open Firebase console -> Project settings -> Add fingerprint
5. Paste your **SHA-1** key
6. Now Reinstall your app from play

Comment: CORRECT! CORRECT!

Comment: How long will take it to setup?

Comment: do we need to reset our phone too.... because i am still getting error

Answer (score 2):

@HandyPawan's mentioned answer completely right here but as Google Console updated now the steps are -

1. Go to google play console
2. **Release -> Setup -> App Integrity**
3. copy SHA-1 certificate fingerprint in (App signing certificate) but no include
   (SHA1: )
4. Open Firebase console -> Project settings -> Add fingerprint
5. Paste your SHA-1 key
6. Now Reinstall your app from play

Comment: I did exactly as you said, but I still do not receive the OTP. Should I remove the other SHA-1 which was already there? I reinstalled the app, cleared the cache, restarted the device.

Comment: Are you getting that OTP in debug app? Try explain it clearly... that what kind of OTP you are talking about. Is it that from Firebase authentication ?

Comment: what do you mean "Now Reinstall your app from play"?

Answer (score 1):

After you copied SHA1 key do you download `google-services.json` in your project?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded it and added it to the project

Answer (score 1):

In my case, SHA-1 alone didn't work until I pasted my SHA-256.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I uploaded to the Play Store signed with my existing SHAs, which have been set in my Firebase App fingerprints for a long time with SMS autocomplete working fine. I also see the same SHA keys listed in the Play Store for my app.

However now the SMS outbound txt looks different and shows my package name with "(unverified)", and no 11 digit hash at the end as before. Needless to say, the autocomplete is no longer working.

Can you confirm you are seeing the 11 char hash at the end of the SMS messages being received? There have been reports that long package names, along with the "(unverified)" appended, may be causing the message to truncate, thereby removing the ending hash.

In which case once verified the package name will be replaced with the app name, the "(unverified)" removed, which should shorten the overall message to include the end hash again.